# Execute SQL Task is behaving Different loading start date and End date

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In  Script task start_Dt and End_Dt are showing differently but while inserting data into table using Execute SQL Task both columns are loading same date

```
String codeVariable = Dts.Variables["User::Start_Dt"].Value.ToString();
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

When Loading into table :

[image]

Execute SQL :

[image]

can any one suggest me what i'm missing why both dates are coming same

Comment: I think you forgot to include the code for your script task. Also, returning a MessageBox in an SSIS package is a bad idea; if you *forget* to remove the code when you deploy the package it will fail; due there being no display layer for said message box.

Comment: @Larnu to show the dates i have put message Box and i will remove those . I will add the code

Comment: You need to include the final mapping of variable to column.  Your single line of codeVariable doesn't tell us the whole story.

Comment: are you setting the start and end time variables in the same script task?  then just using a message box between to show what the value is for troubleshooting purposes?   That would be why without message box they are the same, but different when you add the message box.  We need more details.

Comment: @TimMylott I'm using different script tasks one for start date and end date.In the script task i'm putting the single code in script task

Comment: i have debugged by using Break points and Locals for variable Start_Dt and End_Dt are getting same date.Why?

Comment: what is the code in each of the script task where you are setting the Start_Dt and End_Dt?  and what are you executing in the execute sql task?